# I use PHPrunner but all string field are empty

Tags: php, iis-7

I use PHPRunner, I create a proyect and works fine on simulation, but when I upload to my server string fields are not showing. I get no error...

Comment: So either you will share some code or we're going to proclaim your problem is aardvarks (or we'll close the question)

Comment: I have no code and no error, thats the problem. I create a basic proyect with phprunner. My server is IIS7 with php5.3 and SQL Server 2012. Maybe, I don't know, it's not a phorunner problem but a php / iis7 well know problem... I have wordpress running on that IIS (another IIS site) with no problem at all

Comment: The only thing I can even suggest at this point is to check your logs and work from there. Without code or errors I don't think we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

PHPRunner generates this code:
$fieldVal = sqlsrv_get_field( $qHanle, $j );

And that's why strings are not showing. I change to

$fieldVal = sqlsrv_get_field( $qHanle, $j, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR) );